# Save functionvalues in a file in SparkR

Tags: r, sparkr

I have some calculated values and I want to save them in SparkR.

If I save it as a csv-file

```
write.csv(data, file="/.../data.csv", row.names=FALSE)
```

it takes very long time for some reason. Is there a better way to do this ?

Comment: How is that related to SparkR? `write.csv` doesn't work with Spark data frames.

Comment: I am surprised it doesn't throw an error: did you already collect data to a data.frame? If it is a DataFrame, my guess is it only writes the pointer to a file?

Answer (score 0):

You can save the csv file in /tmp/ for temporary use. But when the cluster restarts, the file will be removed. Specify your the file name as file = "/tmp/filename.csv"

The other choice, you can register your table. 
see https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sparkr.html